# remote address same as server address in php ("::1")

Tags: php

I am having an issue on my server (actually local host). I am working on a project which requires ip address of visitor but php `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is returning always `::1`. I have also tried other functions like this one I found on web.

```
function getRealIpAddr(){
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}
```

but this also returns the same thing. But I wanna get my external ip as I am the visitor at the time which should be `39.35.*.*`. Can anyone please explain, Is there anything wrong with my concepts.

Comment: to get the external ip address(which you want) you must  put your site on some live server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-in-php

Comment: @Raman Are you sure that it does not work without live server because I did not find it anywhere on internet.

Comment: Runing this on the same gateway gave you the `$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` so isn't a bug.

Comment: ::1 is a local machin's IPv6 , if it is IPv4 then it should show 127.0.0.1 .

Comment: @headmax Thanks for this explaination. I didn't knew that and was about to bash my head to the table. Thanks.

Comment: Ok Then problem is solved. The solution is that I have to put the website on the live server right ?

Comment: Thanks every one, I will try it on live server.

Comment: @AneesIjaz lol your script is running just test it at ouside place for example here http://phpfiddle.org/